How to do spring profiles with combinations of multiple values (env + DC)
I have the following SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE = {dev/prod}, {dca,dcb}
Every combination of those two profiles has some unique values, for example
Dev,dca != dev,dcb != prod,dc1 != prod,dcb
Example data would be
dev -
env: dev

dca -
dc: datacenteradev

dcb -
dc: datacenterbdev

prod - 
env: prod

dca -
dc: datacenteraprod

dcb -
dc: datacenterbprod

The values in the example have the env appended to the value, but this is not the case...the values are effectively random and cannot be constructed.

I think this should work:
#---
spring.config.activate.on-profile=dev
env: dev
dca: datacenteradev
dcb: datacenterbdev

#---
spring.config.activate.on-profile=prod
env: prod
dca: datacenteraprod
dcb: datacenterbprod
      
#---
spring.config.activate.on-profile=dca
dc: ${dca}

#---
spring.config.activate.on-profile=dcb
dc: ${dcb}

